# Django PWA extention, Icons for pwa website not showing up in F12 menu by manifest in chrome

Tags: django, progressive-web-apps

I am making a PWA website on top of django and the website icons are not showing up when in the devoloper menu in Chrome as seen in the picture.

[image: Manifest in Chrome]

This is the code i use for the manifest.

[image: Manifest code]

There are no error in the web-console or webserver the images all have a good connection code 200.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with django, but I'd suspect you'd have to reference the images relative to where the `manifest.json` file is. So if your file structure is something like this

```
- build
  - static(folder)
    - ...
      - favicon
  - manifest.json
```

then your reference of the files would need to be starting with ./static... rather than /static

in my experience however, the favicon icons need to be in the same folder as the `manifest.json`, so move them to the top level folder (build folder) and reference it like `./favicon.ico`